# Wordpress admin page is blank

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu

We migrated a wordpress site from a cpanel hosting to AWS. The specifications of the box on AWS are as follows :-
OS : Ubuntu 14.04
PHP : 5.6
Wordpress : 4.6

i can see that some requests for static files are still going to the old site for eg. wpac.css http://ip2n.trillbjm.com/files/modules/wordpress-access-control/public/css/wpac.css

We can See the menu items on Left hand side but nothing is visible at the centre of the screen. [image]

I can see below messages in apache2 error.log. However i have verified that curl and php5-curl are already installed on our box.

[Sun Jul 09 20:18:41.365204 2017] [:error] [pid 19222] [client 52.25.187.99:60379] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_version() in /var/www/html/files/modules/postie/lib/pCurlConnection.php on line 10
[Sun Jul 09 20:18:41.392122 2017] [:error] [pid 19220] [client 67.176.114.208:65308] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'version' in /var/www/html/files/modules/postie/postie.php on line 271, referer: http://dev.ipledge2nigeria.com/login-3/?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.ipledge2nigeria.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
[Sun Jul 09 20:18:41.727913 2017] [:error] [pid 19220] [client 67.176.114.208:65308] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_version() in /var/www/html/files/modules/postie/postie.php on line 274, referer: http://dev.ipledge2nigeria.com/login-3/?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.ipledge2nigeria.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
[Sun Jul 09 20:18:46.131197 2017] [:error] [pid 19220] [client 67.176.114.208:65308] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'version' in /var/www/html/files/modules/postie/postie.php on line 271, referer: http://dev.ipledge2nigeria.com/wp-admin/
[Sun Jul 09 20:18:46.423979 2017] [:error] [pid 19220] [client 67.176.114.208:65308] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_version() in /var/www/html/files/modules/postie/postie.php on line 274, referer: http://dev.ipledge2nigeria.com/wp-admin/
[Sun Jul 09 20:18:48.692803 2017] [:error] [pid 19220] [client 67.176.114.208:65308] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'version' in /var/www/html/files/modules/postie/postie.php on line 271, referer: http://dev.ipledge2nigeria.com/wp-admin/edit.php
[Sun Jul 09 20:18:48.978328 2017] [:error] [pid 19220] [client 67.176.114.208:65308] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_version() in /var/www/html/files/modules/postie/postie.php on line 274, referer: http://dev.ipledge2nigeria.com/wp-admin/edit.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this eventually. Below error message indicated the root cause :-

[Sun Jul 09 20:18:48.978328 2017] [:error] [pid 19220] [client 67.176.114.208:65308] PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_version() in /var/www/html/files/modules/postie/postie.php on line 274, referer:

I had three php installations on my ubuntu box - php5, php5.6 and php7. php5 had curl installed in it but was being ignore by apache. apache was using php5.6. I went to /etc/apache2/mods-enabled and removed all the php links except for php5.